# User Change Font of Selected Text in RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, fonts, richtextbox

This should be easy, however it is eluding me. I have a RichTextBox in VB.NET that the user enters text in. I want them to be able to select some text, then change the font properties of the selection.

Comment: See [SelectionFont](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I have quickly written up for you.
It will get ALL of the installed fonts on the system and add them to a combobox, so you wont have to add them all manually.
Also I have made it so whenever you change the font type for a combobox that I have added, It will update the RichTextBox's font.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Public Class Form1
''CREATE ANOTHER COMBOBOX TO CHANGE THE SIZE OF THE TEXT USING THE SAME METHOD
''AS THE FONT COMBOBOX.
Dim FONTSIZE = 8
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim InstalledFonts = New InstalledFontCollection
    Dim FontFamilies() As FontFamily = InstalledFonts.Families

    For Each Font As FontFamily In FontFamilies
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Font.Name)
    Next
    ''THE END USER WONT BE ABOUT TO EDIT THE INSTALLED ITEMS IN THE COMBOBOX
    ''THE STARTING FONT IS CONSOLAS
    ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    ComboBox1.Text = "Consolas"
    End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ''THIS WILL CHANGE THE HIGHLIGHTED "SELECTED" TEXT FONT ONLY
    ''AS ASKED FOR IN QUESTION
    RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New Drawing.Font(ComboBox1.Text, FONTSIZE)
End Sub
End Class
```

You will need to add a combobox to your form and a richtextbox for this too work.
If you have any trouble, let me know and I'll try and help you work.

Comment: Wouldn't a `FontDialog` be better for this purpose? :)

Comment: Hahaha where is the fun in that?

Comment: Uuh... uuuuuh... Okay, nothing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Werdna, your answer gave me some direction. I did go with the FontDialog as in the end I wanted to allow other font changes such as style and color.

```
Private Sub rtf_Notes_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles rtf_Notes.MouseUp
    'Test for right-click
    If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) Then
        With FontDialog1
            .ShowColor = True
            If (.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
                rtf_Notes.SelectionFont = New Drawing.Font(.Font.Name, .Font.Size, .Font.Style)
                rtf_Notes.SelectionColor = .Color
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, so I have not been getting enough sleep. Deleted the duplicate .ShowDialog and all is well.